# How to fix Owl carousel problem in magento2

Tags: javascript, magento2, owl-carousel

please see the first banner in this website 'https://magento-261664-864122.cloudwaysapps.com/', Owl works only when I click on the banner image

when fully page loaded website look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvlIi.jpg)
and when click on banner website look like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGbTF.jpg)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i mean owl carousel not working in my magento2 website, You will understand when you visit this website https://magento-261664-864122.cloudwaysapps.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer Owl casual argument 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html
autoplay:true

```
<script>
(function  () {
    require(["jquery","owlcarousel"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#owlslider").owlCarousel({
                navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
                autoPlay: true, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds 
                items : 1
            });
        });
    });
})();
</script>
```